# rostango unsupported method at runtime

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the instructions here:
https://github.com/ologic/Tango/wiki/ROSTango-Instructions

I am able to successfully catkin_make and open the project in tango-studio (0.6.1).

When I try to run any of the apps, it sees the tango tablet, Target device: google-yellowstone....  I select it and then the process fails with:
Unsupported method: AndroidArtifact.getOutputFile().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method

I have the same issue with the samples built from here:
https://github.com/ologic/Tango/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Tango-and-ROS
and submitted a ros.answers question for that as well:
http://answers.ros.org/question/199283/ros-tango-samples-dont-run/

The gradle build messages show that "Tooling API is using target Gradle version 1.12" which could go with plugin version 0.11 but I don't know how to check for the Android Gradle Plugin version (it should be 0.11 to work with studio version 0.6.1) and I am pretty sure this problem is due to using the wrong Plugin version.

I think that all I have to do is edit the build.gradle file to select plugin version 0.11, but I don't know how to do that.  I tried editing build.gradle , changing

classpath group: 'org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap', name: 'gradle_plugins', version: '0.1.22'

to a variety of different versions (0.11 (not found), 0.11+ (not found), 0.1+ (found, but generates the same error)).

Here is the relevant section of build.gradle:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}

buildscript {
    def rosMavenPath = "$System.env.ROS_MAVEN_PATH".split(':').collect { 'file://' + it }
    def rosMavenRepository = "$System.env.ROS_MAVEN_REPOSITORY"
    repositories {
        rosMavenPath.each { p ->
            maven {
                url p
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url rosMavenRepository
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap', name: 'gradle_plugins', version: '0.1.22'
        // compile 'org.ros.tf2:tf2_ros:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199331/rostango-unsupported-method-at-runtime/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2014-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sledgehammer approach seems to have worked.
In the file:

```
~/rjandroid/src/ROSTango/ROSTango/src/rostango/build.gradle
```

I added this to the dependencies  section:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
```

and that by itself fails, but when you also add

```
jcenter()
```

to the repositories section, the programs load onto the Tango and run.

I have no idea whether this will actually work, but if it does, then these seem like very odd things for the repo to have left out of the build.grable file.

Since I also had this problem with the android_core build, I changed the build.gradle files located in the following directories:

```
~/rjandroid/src/android_core
~/rjandroid/src/android_extras
```

in addition to

```
~/rjandroid/src/ROSTango/ROSTango/src/rostango
```

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2014-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0